# Left pad varchar to certain length in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to left pad int number with 12 digits as 0 and starting with character as 'P'

E.g if number is 345
Then output should be '`P00000000345`'

My Code :

```
Declare @a int
Set @a =8756
Select Right('P00000000000' +Cast(@a As Varchar(11)),12)
```

**DB : SQL SERVER 2008**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Declare @a int
Set @a =8756
Select 'P' + REPLACE(STR(@a, 11), SPACE(1), '0')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18547

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Declare @a int
Set @a =8756
Select 'P'+Right('00000000000' +Cast(@a As Varchar(11)),11)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mostly correct, but should apply the `P` as a separate step:

```
Declare @a int
Set @a =8756
Select 'P' + Right('000000000000' +Cast(@a As Varchar(11)),12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Select Right('P00000000000' +Cast(@a As Varchar(11)),12)
```

to

```
Select 'P' + Right('00000000000' +Cast(@a As Varchar(11)),11)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18537)

Answer (score 0):

This will left pad the number with zeros. 11 zeros and prepend the 'P', so a total of 12 chars.

```
declare @a int
set @a = 234
select @a as ORIG, 'P' || str(@a, 11, '0') as CHAR12_STRING
```